# Show multiple images on one page of PDF using aspose

Tags: c#, pdf, c#-3.0, aspose.pdf

I am trying to show multiple images on one page in PDF
if I have 40 images it is creating 47 pages in pdf
how can I display one or two images on one page

Can you please help me

Comment: You can please try adding the ImageStamp in PDF in order to display more than one image (https://docs.aspose.com/pdf/net/image-stamps-in-pdf-page/). You can specify the image XIndent and YIndent in order to place images at your desired location. This is Asad Ali and I work as a Developer Evangelist at Aspose.

Comment: *I am trying to show multiple images on one page in PDF if I have 40 images it is creating 47 pages in pdf* - You've tagged this [tag:c#] so the problem seems to be with some code you wrote.  For us to help you, please [edit] your question to share a [mcve] showing the code that doesn't work.  Without that we would just be guessing where you are going wrong.  See [ask]: *Help others reproduce the problem...  if your problem is with code you've written, you should include some... Include just enough code to allow others to reproduce the problem.*